Piston cylinder question
I have a simple question, but it confuses me a lot.
Suppose we have a piston-cylinder device that is being heated, say, at the rate of Q_dot. All other faces can be assumed to be adiabatic. The surrounding can be considered p_atm, and the piston has mass M. The process should be isobaric (constant pressure).

WHY DOES THAN THE PISTON MOVE? The pressure inside and outside remains the same, which results in the net zero force on the piston.
WILL THE PISTON EVER STOP?
HOW WOULD VOLUME AND TEMPERATURE VARY WITH TIME?
This question seems to be silly, but it confuses me a lot.


Does this answer your question? How can isobaric system do work?

Don't think this question should be closed. The suggested duplicate question does not answer parts 2 and 3 of this question or the basic misunderstanding expressed in this question. Also the answer to the linked question is wrong.


We assume the system changes slowly enough over time so that the gas is essentially at a constant pressure. The volume and/or temperature will change so that system is always at mechanical equilibrium.

Yes, the piston stops at equilibrium

Volume changes by the piston moving. The temperature can change by either work being done on/by the system, or by allowing energy exchange as heat into/out of the system.




1)WHY DOES THAN THE PISTON MOVE? The pressure inside and outside remains
the same, which results in the net zero force on the piston.

Of course there has to be a pressure difference for the piston to move. Notice that the definition of "isobaric" is a process that occurs at constant pressure which is subtlety different from saying the pressure inside is as the pressure the outside.  Generally, isobaric process are slow processes that allow the pressure to inside and outside to equalise as much as possible, because if there is a large pressure difference the piston will accelerate which in turn drops the pressure which makes it difficult to maintain a constant pressure.
Consider a situation where the heater is initially off the gas inside the cylinder is cold. When the heater is turned on the gas heats up and the pressure increases. This means this initial phase is not isobaric. The piston starts to move outwards and its velocity increases until it reaches an equilibrium where the increasing volume per unit time keeps the pressure constant and the system is now officially an isobaric system.


WILL THE PISTON EVER STOP?


You have stated that energy is continually added as heat. While energy continues to be added, the piston will have to continue to move. If the piston stops while heat energy continues to added the pressure will have to rise. Of course there will come a time when the gas pressure inside the cylinder approaches being a vacuum and the molecules inside the the cylinder are so widely dispersed that might only make contact with the heated surface or the piston maybe once a year and the process will no longer be a smooth continuous process.


HOW WOULD VOLUME AND TEMPERATURE VARY WITH TIME?


Since pressure is constant over time the volume will be increasing linearly over time and the temperature will remain constant, because the heat energy being added is continually converted to the kinetic energy of the piston instead of raising the temperature of the gas.
This obviously implies the gas in the cylinder does not adhere to the ideal gas ($PV = nRT$), because if the left side is increasing due to V increasing and everything on the right is constant, then there is a contradiction. This is because the ideal gas law applies to a closed system where no energy leaves or exits the system, but this set up is for an open system where energy is being added to the system constantly, so the regular ideal gas law for closed systems does not apply here.

Concerning the third point, you mentioned that the pressure and temperature will remain constant, and the volume will increase linearly over time. Don't you feel that if this is the case, then the ideal gas in the cylinder won't adhere to the ideal gas equation?

@Ankush  Added a bit to my answer to address that.
